# Holistic enzyme activity determination with computation

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, proteomics, structural-biology

I'm currently working on a program which will determine the activity difference between an original enzyme and a variant with just 1 or 2 variants. Of course, I'm not talking about the "kinetic activity", but some indications of a probable activity difference should be given. The system has to be sensitive enough to determine the probable activity difference between unthought-of variants.

From the information that I've got from my research, there is two option. I can use one of 3 quantitive enzyme reaction analysis tools (such as EVB, FEB and LRA) or their hybrids.

EVB => Empirical Valence Bond

FEB => Free Energy Perturbation

LRA => Linear Response Approximation

Source:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can-the-activity-of-proteins-be-studied-using-molecular-dynamic-simulations

Now, my questions are: - Does these application be used for such purpose? - For an accurate prediction of  enzyme activity difference, are these programs good enough or require developement? - Which one of them can give the best result? - And lastly, are QM/MM methods a must for an accurate answer?

I'm a high school student so sorry if my questions sound dumb.
If you can answer my inquiry's I would appreciate it:)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your title says `holistic`. This is a tad problematic as there's layers upon layers. Say, post-translation regulation, inhibiting metabolites, interacting protein etc. That is why when talking of an enzyme inhibitor, at the biochemical level one speaks in terms of k_i (inhibition constant), while at the cellular level ("holistic") one talks of IC50.

This could be a biocatalysis/synthetic biology problem (make an enzyme better) or translational medicine problem (why is this mutation pathogenic).

In terms of *in silico* enzyme design, one can have all sorts of issues that need to be addressed:

- catalysis
- side reactions
- stability
- aggregation
- solubility

Also there's the expression problems, which may be due to subpar promoter, insufficient cofactors and poor codon usage.

For clinical variant assessment, a variant may:

- destabilise leaving to degradation
- remove a post-translational modification
- disrupt the active site, affecting catalysis
- lose a binding partner
- result in incorrect localisation
- result in solubility issues

So force-field scores are not the sole solution. Furthermore, a forcefield method gives one a ∆∆G (difference in relative Gibbs free energy), not a K_M (Michaelis constant) and a k_cat (catalytic rate), although it is somewhat possible to calculate these, or a relative variant of these.

> a variant with just 1 or 2 variants

A variant protein can have one or two *mutations* (e.g. G10R) in its sequence. A *mutant* and a *variant* are near synonyms, but variant is generally intended to be a mutant in a population.

> Does these application be used for such purpose?

For enzyme design MD simulations are not generally the first step. Rosetta pmut_scan for example is a nice starting step as the mutational landscape of a protein is N^19, while a MD simulation takes weeks and 6+ core per single variant.
This calculates only an increase in stability (relative difference in Gibbs folding energy), not reactivity. For that you can use a transition state, whose results are inaccurate, but majorly affected by the set-up, i.e. junk-in junk-out plays a big part. There's a saying 'a week in the lab saves you an hour at the library': this is backwards for sarcasm as it happens too often, namely that is background research is always a lifesaver. An QM-MD simulation on the wild type reaction definitely can help in elucidating things if it is not clear.

### Online tools

Generally, however, there are resources out there to do many stability calculations already.

**SynBio** If you are interested in picking a residue or two to make an enzyme more stable, without resorting to a thermophilic enzyme, [PROSS](https://pross.weizmann.ac.il/step/pross-terms/) is a very nice tool.

**Clinical** (Caveat: If your variant is a variant that affects you, a friend or a relative, you/they should speak to a genetic councillor and not do research on it yourself) There are several tools that can describe a variant at the protein level. Do remember that ∆∆G is a potential so more negative is more stable —except in SDM where the score is inverted.

- [Missense3D](http://www.sbg.bio.ic.ac.uk/%7Emissense3d/)
- [Venus](https://venus.sgc.ox.ac.uk)
- [Miscast](http://miscast.broadinstitute.org/)
- [SDM](http://www-cryst.bioc.cam.ac.uk/%7Esdm/sdm.php)